# Implementation of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I'm relatively new to Python (but not with programming) and I'm getting quite confused with how dictionaries work in Python. I have a program that saves the score of a current player. Whenever the game ends, I need to save the score in a dictionary with keywords 'username', 'runtime', and 'errors'. So my final output would be something like:

Score - Username - RunTime - Error

10-------Jane--------7s--------3--

15-------Brian-------7s--------3--

12-------Dave--------7s--------3--

09-------Aura--------7s--------3--

In the terminal, I should display the output of the dictionary which I think should be:

```
{ '10' : ['username': Jane, 'runtime': 7s, 'errors':3], '15' : ['username': Brian, 'runtime': 7s, 'errors':3], and so on and so forth
```

Is this possible? What should be the workaround here? Thank you for the help

Comment: 1. Your inner structure are lists, not dictionaries. 2. Why would the score be the outer keys? can't 2 users get the same score? It feels like the username should be the outer key (if at all. Why not just have a list of dictionaries?, ie `[{'username': 'Jane', 'runtime': '7s', 'score': 10}, {'username': 'Brian', 'runtime': '7s', 'score': 15}]`)

Comment: Actually, I realized it's not the problem that confuses me. It's the instruction. The instruction says, "after the game is done, SAVE THE SCORE IN A DICTIONARY WITH KEYS USERNAME, TIME, AND ERRORS". I don't exactly know what that means or what the output should be. Does this makes sense?

Comment: The thing that will make the most sense would be to ask whoever wrote the instructions.

Comment: It's like the goal is somehow similar in a "leaderboard" concept.

Comment: Trying to make sense out of the instructions. As even score or username can repeat in the final output but combinations of username,runtime and errors might not repeat and can be treated as a key and value being the score

Comment: I guess the instruction is really ambiguous. But I guess, I should really sort out the username as the key. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dictionary element consists of 2 parts:
- key
- value
Keys should be unique and immutable (string, integers, sets etc..)
The score is immutable (integer) but probably not unique. In case several players get the same amounts of scores, you will not be able to store their data under the same key.

Consider the following structures:

1. DICTIONARY WITH USERNAME AS A KEY
   {Username: [Score, RunTime, Error], ...}
2. LIST OF LISTS
   [[Username, Score, RunTime, Error], ...]

Comment: dictionary with username as a key might work and makes more sense. I just currently don't know how to do it syntactically (assigning list as a value for the key) but will explore it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To save the score in a dictionary with keys username :

```
scores = {}
scores["Name"] = [runtime, score]
```

then use `scores["Name"][0] or score["Name"][1]`

Or if you realy want to use the keys like "score" or "runtime" you can use an other dict in the score dict.

```
scores = {}
scores["Name"] = {"runtime": 10, "score": 100}
```

And use `scores["Name"]["score"] or scores["Name"]["runtime"]` to get the score or the runtime.